# Schema design in MongoDB - Many to one relationships

Tags: mongodb, one-to-many

I'm planning to build a community, using MongoDB for the first time.
I think I've got the most of it figured out, except...

Normally i would make joins in MySQL to get the author name along with every post.

In Mongo I have a hard time making up my mind. As I see it, I have the following 2 options:

**1)** 
Store user ID, and name in the post document.
Downside: Database would be larger that option 2.
I would be forced to update every post that user has ever written, in case the username is changed.

**2)**
Store the user ID only in the post document.
Downside: Each unique user of 10-50 documents has to be queried, to print the username with the post.

Is there a 3rd option that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It boils down to: denormalize user name or not.
In term of schema, I don't see any other reasonable choice (let's not talk about storing posts in the user document).

However, you have a lot of options regarding implementation, such as:

- disallowing username change
- caching user-id<->user-name

It all depends on your cardinality, the type of request you'll be doing, and how much you plan to scale your tiers (app tier & clients are generally easier to scale horizontally than databases, wether they're SQL or not).

If you can afford it, I'd go with a normalized model, a cache of users (you'll probably want to add avatars, reputation or badges at some point) and - even in SQL - no joins (or rather a client side join).